# Can two diffrent keys store the same data without duplicate in Redis C++

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

I want that two different keys hold the same data without duplicat this data.

for example:
key1 and key2 holds the same hash (without duplicat it in memory)

There such a way to do it in Redis?

Comment: NO, you CANNOT. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you really need to do this, you'd probably do it in two steps. Key->ID, ID->data. You'd have only one ID and one data item. You'd have two keys, both storing the same ID. That ID would be something like a 32-bit int, so storing two copies wouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: I don't know redis so I don't know what store you use. But if it's C++ maybe you can do something with a shared_ptr to the data? And store the shared_ptr instead? Or create a proxy class that refers to the data and store that class instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin There is a way to know that ID for example is a key? because when I read this in my program, I want to know if I need to continue to next key to get data or if this the data I need

Comment: In our system there are through several options to reach the same information, so there may be several keys that will symbolize the same information, and I would have preferred as little information duplication as possible @for_stack

Comment: @MoranLev In that case, you need to do a mapping from multiple keys to an ID, as Jerry mentioned in comment.

Comment: @MoranLev: AFAIK, you'd have to store that explicitly with the data. For example, prepend one byte to your data, containing `0` to say: "this is an ID" or `1` to say: "this is actual data". If you know enough about your data, you might be able to find a bit that's never set (or never clear) in real data, and assure it's always the opposite in your ID (but I don't know enough about your data to say whether you can do that or not).

Comment: @for_stack's answer "NO" is correct. It should be posted as an answer. Btw, this question is about Redis, the server, not the clients, so the hiredis tag is not relevant. Redis is implemented in C, not C++.